# What is the differences between the below 2 iptable rules?

Tags: port-forwarding, openvpn, iptables

I have a setup like below.

```
RaspberryPI <==> OpenVPN Server <==> Internet <==> Client PC
```

The RaspberryPI have an SSH server that is on a Dynamic IP.
It is tunneled through the OpenVPN server so that the SSH server can be accessed via the OpenVPN Server's Public IP.

My question is, why Rule 1 allows successful SSH connection from Client PC to SSH Server via OpenVPN Public IP but not Rule 2?

**Rule 1:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2200 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:22
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.8.0.2 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

**Rule 2:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d OPENVPN.SERVER.PUBLIC.IP -p tcp --dport 2200 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:22
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.8.0.2 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Note: 10.8.0.2 would be the OpenVPN assigned private IP for the RaspberryPI.

The rest of my iptable rule which remain constant is as below.

```
[root@OpenVPN ~]# iptables -t filter -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 13670 packets, 1610K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2586  196K ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   55  7015 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   57  7031 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 13877 packets, 2447K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         


[root@OpenVPN ~]# iptables -t nat -L -v -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 860 packets, 50498 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 834 packets, 48572 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2585 packets, 197K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2588 packets, 198K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   26  1926 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
```

Below is the ifconfig result on the OpenVPN Server.

```
[root@OpenVPN ~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 192.168.0.XX  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fXX0::c:XXXf:XXdf:XXX0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 343049  bytes 388973010 (370.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 126179  bytes 13601264 (12.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 95  bytes 14596 (14.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 95  bytes 14596 (14.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.XX.XX  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.XX.XX
        inet6 fXX0::cXXX:f7XX:XXX3:XXe8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 64  bytes 7575 (7.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 84  bytes 8553 (8.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's most likely because your OpenVPN server's public IP address *does not belong to the server.* Note the address shown in your ifconfig output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 192.168.0.XX  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

So that likely means your VPN server *itself* is already behind NAT (presumably 1:1 NAT), and it never actually receives packets having the public IP address – the only `-d` address it ever sees is the 192.168.0.XX one.

---

*(But keep in mind that ifconfig can lie. If eth0 had multiple addresses assigned, ifconfig would only show the first one – you would need to use `ip addr` to see them all.)*